# React Router Cannot Get / depending on onEnter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-routing

I am new to React and hoping someone can shed some light on why this is happening and how to debug it.

I have the following routes defined:

```
export default (withHistory, onUpdate) => {
  const history = withHistory?
              (Modernizr.history ?
                new BrowserHistory
              : new HashHistory)
            : null;
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/' component={Home} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Router>
  );
};
```

`requireAuth` is supposed to check if the user is logged in and redirect them to the login page if not:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, transition) {
  transition.to("/login");
}
```

If I leave the `transtion.to` call in and browse to the root URL I just see a message that says, "Cannot Get /" with no error messages in the debugger. Putting a breakpoint on that line doesn't seem to do anything.

What's especially odd is that if I replace `transition.to(...)` with a `debugger;` statement, then the method is called and routing works perfectly fine.

I must have a misunderstanding on something, any ideas on what that is?

Edit: I should add that navigating to `host:port/login` works fine, so I know the `login` route works.

Comment: What version of react-router? 1.x?

Comment: I am using version 1.0.0-beta3 of react-router. I did try upgrading the version I was using, but I ended up solving it an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from an Angular background I had incorrectly assumed that routing was happening entirely client-side. It's possible to use react-router for both client-side *and* server side routing.

The `transition.to` call worked fine on the client-side, but threw an exception when server-side routing kicked in and returned the `Cannot GET /` page. The exception was being caught but nothing logged.

I added an if statement to see if we were running on the client:

```
if(window.location) {
    if(!loggedIn) {
        transition.to("/login");
    }
 }
```

There is probably a better way to handle this and if I figure that out eventually I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current docs, the `onEnter` hook receives a `replace` function as its second param. i.e.

```
type EnterHook = (nextState: RouterState, replace: RedirectFunction, callback?: Function) => any;
```

Are you using a different version of react-router? I tried looking through the alternate version docs for an `onEnter` hook that takes a `transition` object as its second param, but I didn't have much luck in finding anything.

Comment: I am using version 1.0.0-beta3 of react-router, which passes the Transition object and not the replace function. I did try upgrading the version I was using, but I ended up solving it an easier way.